# Issue with running Roboflow inference in Python Script using Google Cloud Functions API

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, roboflow

I intend to capture an image via mobile and send the image to a python script running as a Google Cloud Function which calls my trained Roboflow object detection model.

Here is the python script on Google Cloud Functions to run inference on the received image.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from roboflow import Roboflow

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up your Roboflow API key, model endpoint, and version
ROBOFLOW_API_KEY = "XXX"
ROBOFLOW_MODEL_ENDPOINT = "XXX"
ROBOFLOW_VERSION = "X"

# Initialize the Roboflow client
rf = Roboflow(api_key=ROBOFLOW_API_KEY)
project = rf.workspace().project(ROBOFLOW_MODEL_ENDPOINT)
model = project.version(ROBOFLOW_VERSION).model


@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload(request):
    # Receive the incoming image file from the Android app
    image_file = request.files["image"]
    image_data = image_file.read()
    image_filename = image_file.filename

    # Convert the image data to a base64 encoded string
    base64_img_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    # Run inference on the image using the Roboflow API
    prediction = model.predict(base64_img_data, confidence=40, overlap=30)
    results = prediction.json()

    # Return the results of the inference
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now, when I try to test this script by sending a local image via the below, it seems like classification.py within the roboflow doesn’t like the data received and throws errors.

```
# Send the image data to the Cloud Function using a POST request with multipart/form-data
response = requests.post(cloud_function_url, files={"image": ("image.jpg", image_data, "image/jpeg")})
```

Log Trace:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 38, in upload prediction = model.predict(base64_img_data) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/roboflow/models/classification.py", line 54, in predict self.__exception_check(image_path_check=image_path) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/roboflow/models/classification.py", line 126, in __exception_check raise Exception("Image does not exist at " + image_path_check + "!") TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @BradDwyer Thanks for asking. I have added it above.